# Dynamics CRM - get access token without Azure

Tags: dynamics-crm, token, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I founded a lot of libs on GitHub which help to get token.
For example - https://github.com/AleksandrRogov/DynamicsWebApi

[image]

But I have no 'authorityUrl' because not using Azure. How I can get token without Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Azure Active Directory (ADAL) is prerequisite to use CRM Web API.

Similar discussion happened in [CRM community](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/210065) also.